# VB.net Use Linklabel.name as variable

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use a linklabel.name as a form type. Is this possible? I am trying to do this in such a way to reduce the amount of code I am writing.

```
Dim lnklblName As String
Private Sub Create_MasterControls()
    Dim LinkLabelEMP As LinkLabel
    LinkLabelEMP = New LinkLabel()
    LinkLabelEMP.AutoSize = True
    LinkLabelEMP.Location = New Point(25, 25)
    LinkLabelEMP.Name = "frmEmployee"
    LinkLabelEMP.Size = New Size(135, 15)
    LinkLabelEMP.Text = "Employee Edit"
    pnlDS.Controls.Add(LinkLabelEMP)
End Sub
Private Sub lnk_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs)

    Dim lnk As LinkLabel = CType(sender, LinkLabel)

    lnklblName = lnk.Name

End Sub
Private Sub OpenForm()

    Dim Frm_New As New lnklblname()
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    Frm_New.MdiParent = ParentForm
    Frm_New.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    'MainMenu.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    'Display the new form.
    Frm_New.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: Controls make for horrible code variables

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` property of a `LinkLabel`, or any control for that matter, contains a `String` object.  It can thus be used anywhere that a `String` can be used.  If you could use "Hello World" somewhere then you can't use the `Name` of a control either,  Would this make sense?

```
Dim Frm_New As New "Hello World"()
```